# JavaScript switch with variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, switch-statement

I want to check if a string has a certain letter, and then remove said letter.

jsFiddle — http://jsfiddle.net/nNb5S/6/

For example, if you type...

- XhelloX
- YhelloY
- ZhelloZ

.. in the "input" textarea, the "result" should return...

- hello
- hello
- hello

**I already figured it out, but I was wondering if it could be done via Switch?**

This is my working code ::

```
function doSomething() {

var input = document.getElementById("h"),
    result = document.getElementById("m");

var x = /x/gi;
var y = /y/gi;
var z = /z/gi;

if(input.value.indexOf(x)) {
    result.value = input.value.replace(x,"");        
}
if(input.value.indexOf(y)) {
    result.value = result.value.replace(y,"");        
}
if(input.value.indexOf(z)) {
    result.value = result.value.replace(z,"");        
}

}
```

This is my switch code ::
This below code **ONLY** works when `arg` is defined; but, I don't want to define it.

```
function doSomething() {

var input = document.getElementById("h"),
    result = document.getElementById("m");

var x = /x/gi;
var y = /y/gi;
var z = /z/gi;

/*arg = x;*/ // ONLY WORKS WHEN YOU DEFINE arg.  HOW DO YOU DEFINE arg AS ANY OF THE VARIABLES?

var iO = input.value.indexOf(arg);

switch (arg) {

    case x:
        result.value = input.value.replace(x, "");
    break;
    case y:
        result.value = result.value.replace(y, "");
    break;
    case z:
        result.value = result.value.replace(z, "");
    break;

}
}
```

Comment: Maybe you're complicating things there, wouldn't this work `val.replace(/x|y|z/gi, '')`

Comment: No. That's not what a switch statement is for. You could, however, combine your three regex into a single one `/[xyz]/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOf` is not how you match regular expressions. Neither is `switch`. You’d normally use `RegExp.prototype.test` as follows:

```
if (x.test(input.value)) {
    result.value = input.value.replace(x,"");        
}
```

but seeing as you’re performing replacements, isn’t this more appropriate?

```
result.value = input.value
    .replace(x, '')
    .replace(y, '')
    .replace(z, '');
```

? Unless you really only want to replace matches of the *last* regular expression of the three that matches.

Answer (score 3):

A `switch` statement is definitely **not** the way to go. A much better option would be to use a single regular expression replacement like this:

```
function doSomething() {
    var input = document.getElementById("h"),
        result = document.getElementById("m");
    result.value = input.value.replace(/[xyz]/gi, "");
}
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/nNb5S/7/)

But since you're already using jQuery, this can be simplified even more:

```
function doSomething() {
    $("#m").val($("#h").val().replace(/[xyz]/gi, ""));
}
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/nNb5S/8/)